# Find the length of a string after the first occurrence of a defined sub-string

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have this textarea in html and I am trying to implement something like twitter.

Everytime a user types in '#' I want to highlight the word and at the end of word I want to display a letter count. So for example, " Hi my name is #user123(7) , whats your name?"
I already have the highlighting taken care of, but I am currently lost on the letter count part.
Here is my HTML

```
<div id="inputback" class="format"></div>
<textarea id="input" class="format"></textarea>
```

Javascript

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("input");
var hashflag = 0 ;
var textlength;

textarea.onkeydown = function(e){
  textarea.style.height = "";
  textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
  textlength = textarea.value.length;

  var str = textarea.value;
  str = str.replace(/(\s)([#]\w*)/g, "$1<b>$2</b>");
  $('#inputback').html(str); 
}
```

Here is my CSS

```
    .format
{
    font: 9pt Consolas;

}

#input { border: 1px solid black; background: transparent; z-index: 10; }

#inputback {

    color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px
}
#inputback b
{
    color: black;
    background-color: #808080;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle of what i have accomplished.
http://jsfiddle.net/gjqWy/115/

Thank you in advance!

P.S I dont want to use any plugins or Jquery. Just plain Javascript/html/css

Comment: What's wrong with the good 'ol `.length`? Also: You are already using jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

`.replace` can also take a function as its second paramter:

```
str = str.replace(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g,function(_,a,b) {
    // _ represents the full match - we don't need it here
    // a is the first subpattern
    // b is the second subpattern
    return a+"<b>#"+b+"</b>("+b.length+")";
});
```

I adjusted your regex a bit. Now it will work even if the hash is at the start of the string, and also I took the hash out of the captured group becase a) it's constant, and b) you want the length of the second capture group, and this makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="testForm">
  <input id="A1" type="text"></input>
  <div id="vsA1" class="inputTextSummery">charaters reamining: 40</div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function wordCount(_input, _limit, _summary)
     {
       var limit = _limit; //set limit of charater
         var inputDiv = "#"+_input;  //inout div id
         var displayDiv = "#"+_summary; //display summary div id
       var currentWordCount = 0;  //defualt current charater count
       $(inputDiv).keyup(function(){   //
             currentWordCount = $(inputDiv).val().length;
             var charLeft = limit - currentWordCount;
             if(charLeft >= 0){
              $(displayDiv).html("charaters reamining: "+ (limit - currentWordCount));
             }else{
              $(displayDiv).html("Input has exceed limit!");     
             }
        });     
     }
     wordCount("A1", 40, "vsA1");
```

Comment: Um... what is the purpose of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript `.indexOf` method to find the first occurrence # in the value of your form. What it does is find the first occurrence of '#' in the string your checking and it returns the place of it.

E.G.

```
var string = "This is stackoverflow";
var start = string.indexOf('is'); //Will return as 5
```

After you get that sorted all you will need to do it grab the values after it. Like this

```
var string = "This is stackoverflow";
var start = string.indexOf('is') + 2; //7 (You add 2 because its a 2 letter word)
var end = string.length; //20
var newstring = string.substr(start, end);
```

You can take this information and apply it to your forum by replacing var string with `document.getElementById('inputidhere').value;` And then go from there!

Goodluck! Hope this helped you.